# Disable WordPress 3.6 idle logout / login modal window / session expiration

Tags: login, wp-login-form, authentication, session

I manage a WordPress site hosted at WPEngine that was recently force-upgraded to version 3.6. The upgrade introduced "In-line login following expired sessions", and therein lies the problem. The website is used to manage registrations, room assignments, and other similar functions for a resort. This means that WordPress is often left open, but not actively used, for hours at a time. Before 3.6 everything was fine, but now the client is complaining about the new login modal popping up "often" (every 2-3 minutes or every 20 minutes, depending on who is asked).

My question in short: How do you disable or extend the session responsible for this new modal window?

I have tried using the `auth_cookie_expiration` filter, but this only seems to effect being logged out between page loads and has no effect on the in-line login window.

Full code of what I tried:

```
function myplugin_cookie_expiration( $expiration, $user_id, $remember ) {
// If the "Remember Me" box is checked, keep the session for 14 days. Otherwise
// only keep the session for 2 hours
return $remember ? 1209600 : 7200;
}
add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'myplugin_cookie_expiration', 99, 3 );
```

There seems to be [question similar to this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109802/how-do-i-extend-auto-logout-on-idle-or-redirect-inline-popup) already posted, but there was no response... Thanks in advance for any insight you can offer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It finally hit me that javascript would be behind the interim login modal behavior, and that gave me a new direction in my search. I have disabled the new login popups by adding the following to my theme's `functions.php` file:

```
// Disable login modals introduced in WordPress 3.6
remove_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_auth_check_load' );
```

If anyone's interested in learning more about the new login modals, they are setup in `wp-includes/functions.php` starting on line 3929. You should be able to derive the names and locations of supporting files from the information found there.